# Relative size with font tag in html: Relative to whom?

Tags: html, fonts, font-size, html4

```
<FONT FACE="Comic Sans MS" SIZE=“2“ COLOR="Red">
     This is comical and red and small</FONT><BR>
<FONT FACE="Comic Sans" SIZE="+2" COLOR="Red">
    This is red and big. Is it comical?</FONT><BR>
<FONT FACE="Comic Sans" SIZE="-2" COLOR="Red">
    This is red and big. Is it different?</FONT><BR>
```

Do the +/- values refer to the first  tag or the one preceding the last element?

Comment: I hope you're simply converting some antiquated website to HTML5...

Comment: just curious: why are you interested in the `<font>` element at all?

Comment: Because curiosity killed this cat... I know it is not used since HTML4

Comment: Understood, nothing wrong with curiosity; although, there are lots of things wrong with `<font>`.

Comment: Please tell me a few... even if not related to this question and whether it was replaced by CSS for the same reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is relative to the size set by the [`BASEFONT` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2) (or 3 if no `BASEFONT` element is used). From the HTML 4.01 spec:

> The `BASEFONT` element sets the base font size (using the size
>   attribute). Font size changes achieved with `FONT` are relative to the
>   base font size set by `BASEFONT`. If `BASEFONT` is not used, the default
>   base font size is 3.

However, both `FONT` and `BASEFONT` are deprecated and you should be using CSS instead.

Comment: Is the case same with <BIG> and <SMALL>?

Comment: @popstack - I don't believe so. I think it's up to the browser what happens with `BIG` and `SMALL`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-BIG

Answer (score 0):

Relative resizing implies that the font will be resized relative to the default font size in the user's browser settings. However it is not a good programming practice to mix presentation and declaration code. Use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) instead.